# Sails.js and Waterline: dynamic validation by DB request

Tags: validation, sails.js, waterline

I use Sails 11.1 and Waterline 2.11.2 with a MongoDB database.

I would like to validate data inserted in my "Article" model using a `in` validator for 1 attribute.
Before, I was doing the job with lifecycle callbacks (`beforeCreate` and `beforeUpdate` especially), but it makes double code.

Here you have the model, truncated with just the attribute in question :

```
module.exports =
{
    schema: true,

    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,

    attributes:
    {
        theme:
        {
            model: 'Theme',
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to define it statically:

```
in: ['something', 'something other']
```

I know how to call constants I defined in my `constants.js` file :

```
defaultsTo: function ()
{
    return String(sails.config.constants.articleDefaultTheme);
}
```

But I would like to get all themes in my DB, to have a dynamic `in` validation. So, I wrote this :

```
theme:
{
    model: 'Theme',
    required: true,
    in: function () 
    {
        Theme.find()
        .exec(function (err, themes) 
        {
            if (err)
            {
                return next({ error: 'DB error' });
            }
            else if (themes.length === 0)
            {
                return next({ error: 'themes not found' });
            }
            else
            {
                var theme_ids = [];

                themes.forEach(function (theme, i)
                {
                    theme_ids[i] = theme.theme_id;
                });

                return theme_ids;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it's not working, I have always the "1 attribute is invalid" error. If I write them statically, or if I check in the `beforeCreate` method with another DB request, it works normally.
If I `sails.log()` the returned variable, all the themes ids are here.

I tried to `JSON.stringify()` the returned variable, and also to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` it. I also tried to convert the `theme.theme_id` as a string with the `String()` function, but nothing else...

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug?

You can also check my question here : [Waterline GitHub issues](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1077)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models's configuration at your `attributes` scope at `in` field of course will throw an error, because it should not use a function, especially your function is not return anything, also if you force it to return something, it will return `Promise` that `Theme.find()...` did.

Try use different approach. There are exist [Model Lifecycle Callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks). You can use something like `beforeCreate`, or `beforeValidate` to manually checking your dynamic `Theme`, if it's not valid, return an error.

Or if it's achievable using standard DB relation, just use simple DB relation instead.

Comment: It should not use a function? Are you sure, as I use functions to get my constants, and they work perfectly? About Lifecycle Callbacks, I forgot to mention I was using them before having the idea to use the `in` attribute like this. Added it to my original question. "Or if it's achievable using standard DB relation, just use simple DB relation instead." : how can I do this with Sails, as I use MongoDB (also added to my original question, sorry...)?

Comment: I'm sorry if it can be a function. But AFAIK it should return an object that represented fields configuration instead of promise. Because promise scope/ callback/ any async scope is not sync so it can't be used to define fields configuration.